# Is it possible to change the text being displayed in the PropertyGrid?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to change the text ("Item_Type[] Array") being displayed in the PropertyGrid control when the selected object is an Array?

I like how the grid shows each Item in the hierarchy but I think it would be better if I could change or remove the "Item_Type[] Array" text.

[image]

Comment: Yep, with custom converter. You have to attribute property returning array with it.

Comment: do you have a sample code or link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by using custom converter:

```
public class Test
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ConverterArray))]
    public string[] Property { get; set; } = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = new Test();
    }
}

public class ConverterArray : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destType)
    {
        if (destType == typeof(string))
            return "An array kk?";
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destType);
    }
}
```

Screenshot without converter and with:

[image][image]

---

To see and edit items as expandable list (with indexes as names) inherit converter from `ArrayConverter`.

If you need to remove/add items you must implement custom editor (usually you would make for this another form and use modal editor `UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal`):

```
public class EditorHeaterPID : UITypeEditor
{
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context) => UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;

    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
    {
        SomeForm form = new SomeForm(value);
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            return form.Items;
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: but it's not showing anymore the items in the hierarchy

Comment: Do you want to see indexes or is it ok to use modal `CollectionEditor`?

Comment: In this particular case, the custom converter should inherit `ArrayConverter`

Comment: I would like to preserve the original look but without the "Item_Type[] Array"

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev . I was using custom editor (`UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal` - another form) too be able to add/remove items, but to *preserve* appearance (index as name and editable values) `ArrayConverter` should be used as a base indeed.

Comment: I tried changing the base to `ArrayConverter` but it seems not to work

Comment: @yonan2236, you have to use custom converter (it's called `ConverterArray`), only inherit it like this: `public class ConverterArray: ArrayConverter { ... }`